# Не выводится информация о покрытии тестов

Tags: intellij-idea, тестирование

У меня проблема - не могу проверить покрытие кода тестами. Почему-то проверки не происходит.

`View -> Tool Windows -> Coverage` неактивно, в `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Coverage` включены опции `Show options before applying coverage to the editor` и `Activate Coverage View`.

Я жму `Run 'All Test' with Coverage`, тесты все проходят, но информация о покрытии почему-то не выводится.

Есть подозрение, что проблема в том, что в `Choose Coverage Suite to Dyspalay` ничего нет, но я не понимаю, как туда что-то добавить и почему туда не добавляются мои тесты автоматически.

Правильно ли я понимаю проблему и если да, то как добавить `Coverage suites`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема крылась в том, что нужно в `Run/Debug Configurations` во вкладке `Code Coverage` добавить классы и пакеты по которым я хочу узнать информацию о покрытии.

Answer (score 0):

Распространенная причина такой проблемы - ошибка в пути файла или названии класса.

Класс должен быть назван так же как тестируемый класс + Test. Например: EmployeeService -> EmployeeServiceTest.

А так же путь к тестируемому классу в папке test и путь к классу-тесту в вашей папке кода должны быть прописаны одинаково. Например  src.main.com.example.employeedepartment.EmployeeService ->
src.test.com.example.employeedepartment.EmployeeServiceTest